# How to increment number in pandas column from bottom to top on certain conditions

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I need to create a one new column (Res) in my existing dataframe in which I need to print a numbers on certain conditions. Below is the example.

**Condition**:-

1. If (Date == 01-03-2015) then print 1.
2. and if (Date < 01-03-2015) then increment number from bottom(from 1)  to top  like below example.
3. Else print 0.

Input:-

```
   SR.No    Date     
    1     01-03-2013  
    1     01-06-2013  
    1     01-09-2013  
    1     01-12-2013  
    1     01-03-2014  
    1     01-06-2014  
    1     01-09-2014  
    1     01-12-2014  
    1     01-03-2015  
    1     01-06-2015  
    1     01-09-2015  
    1     01-12-2015  
    2     01-03-2013  
    2     01-06-2013  
    2     01-09-2013  
    2     01-12-2013  
    2     01-03-2014  
    2     01-06-2014  
    2     01-09-2014  
    2     01-12-2014  
    2     **01-03-2015**  
    2     01-06-2015  
    2     01-09-2015  
    2     01-12-2015
```

Output dataframe:-

```
   SR.No   Date       Res
    1     01-03-2013   9
    1     01-06-2013   8
    1     01-09-2013   7
    1     01-12-2013   6
    1     01-03-2014   5
    1     01-06-2014   4
    1     01-09-2014   3
    1     01-12-2014   2
    1     01-03-2015   1
    1     01-06-2015   0
    1     01-09-2015   0
    1     01-12-2015   0
    2     01-03-2013   9
    2     01-06-2013   8
    2     01-09-2013   7
    2     01-12-2013   6
    2     01-03-2014   5
    2     01-06-2014   4
    2     01-09-2014   3
    2     01-12-2014   2
    2     01-03-2015   1
    2     01-06-2015   0
    2     01-09-2015   0
    2     01-12-2015   0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let `df` is your DataFrame. Observed that, data is already sorted by `SR.No` and `Date` columns.

```
threshold_date = '01-03-2015'
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
starters = df[df['Date'] == threshold_date].index
df.loc[starters, 'Res'] = 1
j = 0
for i in starters:
    _index = list(range(2, i+2-j))
    _index.reverse()
    df.loc[j:i-1, 'Res'] = _index
    j = i+1
df.loc[df['Date'] > '01-03-2015', 'Res'] = 0
```

It will produce your required output
[image]

Comment: Thanks Asad :). It's giving the desired output.

Comment: You're welcome @Akib. Just give an up-vote if you consider it your desired answer and mark it.

Comment: Hi Asad I need to solve this problem as well https://stackoverflow.com/a/68067175/16255047

Comment: Sure, please give a vote to this answer if you found it useful by clicking up arrows at the start of the question.

Comment: Your problem has removed. I just tried to open it.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution.
You can first extract the date column into a list and sort the dates in descending order:

```py
dates = df[df["Date"] <= pd.to_datetime("01-03-2015", format="%d-%m-%Y")]["Date"].sort_values(ascending=False).tolist()
```

Then write an apply function that return the index of the given date in the list we created earlier plus 1 (plus 1 as we start at 1) or 0 if not

```py
def count_num_dates_after(date):
    if date in dates:
        return dates.index(date) + 1
    else:
        return 0

df["Res"] = df["Date"].apply(count_num_dates_after)
```

Then you get something like this:

```py
SR.No   Date    Res
0   1   2013-01-03  14
1   1   2013-02-28  13
2   1   2013-04-25  12
3   1   2013-06-21  11
4   1   2013-08-16  10
5   1   2013-10-12  9
6   1   2013-12-07  8
7   1   2014-02-02  7
8   1   2014-03-30  6
9   1   2014-05-26  5
10  2   2014-07-21  4
11  2   2014-09-16  3
12  2   2014-11-11  2
13  2   2015-01-07  1
14  2   2015-03-04  0
15  2   2015-04-30  0
16  2   2015-06-25  0
17  2   2015-08-21  0
18  2   2015-10-16  0
19  2   2015-12-12  0
```